# Other buttons won't appear properly for CSS

Tags: html, css, button

So before I had an issue with the space between each button. Now there is this annoying problem. I have four buttons but only the first 3 are showing up. Why not the FAQ button? It's annoying me. If it's a problem, then I will just create an html code for the 3 buttons then 1 separate for the FAQ button. I just think its odd because before I didn't have an issue. I tried removing the FAQ code from the CSS AND html and then re-pasting it but it gave me the same result.

```
<!CASCADE STUDIOS COPY AND YOU WILL BE CAUGHT">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<style type="text/css">
.helpicon a#editinfo{
    display: block;
    width:138px;
    height:27px;
    background:  url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/editinfo.png) no-repeat;
}

.helpicon a:hover#editinfo{
    background: url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/editinfo0.png) no-repeat;
}
.helpicon a#codes{
    display: block;
    width:138px;
    height:27px;
    background:  url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/codes.png) no-repeat;
}

.helpicon a:hover#codes{
    background: url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/codes0.png) no-repeat;
}
.helpicon a#music{
    display: block;
    width:138px;
    height:27px;
    background:  url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/music.png) no-repeat;
}

.helpicon a:hover#music{
    background: url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/music0.png) no-repeat;

.helpicon a#faq{
    display: block;
    width:138px;
    height:27px;
    background:  url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/FAQ.png) no-repeat;
}

.helpicon a:hover#faq{
    background: url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/FAQ0.png) no-repeat;
}
}
.helpicon a{
  margin: 4px;
  }
</style>

<body>

<div class="helpicon">
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="editinfo"/>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="codes"/>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="music"/>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="faq"/>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's because you didnt close the bracket after .helpicon a:hover#music{

Comment: Oh no I pressed Ctrl+C. When will the invalid-doctype studios catch me? `;)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the correct syntax for the `<a>` tag

```
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="editinfo"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="codes"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="music"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="faq"></a>
```

And there is a missing bracket in the css

```
<!CASCADE STUDIOS COPY AND YOU WILL BE CAUGHT">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<style type="text/css">
.helpicon a#editinfo{
    display: block;
    width:138px;
    height:27px;
    background:  url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/editinfo.png) no-repeat;
}

.helpicon a:hover#editinfo{
    background: url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/editinfo0.png) no-repeat;
}
.helpicon a#codes{
    display: block;
    width:138px;
    height:27px;
    background:  url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/codes.png) no-repeat;
}

.helpicon a:hover#codes{
    background: url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/codes0.png) no-repeat;
}
.helpicon a#music{
    display: block;
    width:138px;
    height:27px;
    background:  url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/music.png) no-repeat;
}

.helpicon a:hover#music{
    background: url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/music0.png) no-repeat;
}
.helpicon a#faq{
    display: block;
    width:138px;
    height:27px;
    background:  url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/FAQ.png) no-repeat;
}

.helpicon a:hover#faq{
    background: url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/FAQ0.png) no-repeat;
}

.helpicon a{
  margin: 4px;
  }
</style>

<body>

<div class="helpicon">
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="editinfo"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="codes"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="music"></a>
<a href="http://www.twitter.com" id="faq"></a>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your closing `}` from this section:

```css
.helpicon a:hover#codes{
    background: url(http://icpy.webs.com/button/codes0.png) no-repeat;
```